# Capistrano - Forward key to work composer properly

Tags: php, symfony, capistrano, composer-php, capifony

While deploying I got:

```
--> Updating Composer dependencies
....
** [out :: myproj] Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/mmoreramerino/GearmanBundle/zipball/e0fa6c06bc5c7a5aaddaf33d5b0595ce280f7538, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
** [out :: myproj] The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in /website_dir/.composer/config.json, your password will not be stored
** [out :: myproj] To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications
** [out :: myproj] Username:
```

All the other repos are downloaded successfully.
At this step I can't enter my username and.. I don't want to)

Dependency in composer.json:

```
"Mmoreramerino/GearmanBundle": "dev-development",
```

**EDIT**:
Issue is not in composer. Issue is in capistrano that runs composer update after deploying.

I have a production server. I can access it like:

```
$ ssh -A my_server
```

And can clone this repo manually. Because in this way I use my key in production server.

Now I have in capistrano's deploy.rb:

```
ssh_options[:keys] =            %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
ssh_options[:forward_agent] =   true
```

So deploying should use my key in this key.

But I got an error in the composer's update in capistrano's step.

**Edit 2**:

```
$ ps aux | grep "ssh-agent"
dmitry    1772  0.0  0.0  73444   452 ?        Ss   09:25   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /bin/sh -c exec -l /bin/bash -c "startxfce4"
dmitry   18541  0.0  0.0 109184   884 pts/0    S+   17:25   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh-agent
```

Comment: lol you completely changed the question to an absolutely new one ... Thanks for wasting my time ... you asked "how to avoid typing the username/password?" - i kindly edited your question to make it more obvious, provided a valid and and working answer and now youre changing it to some capistrano question? Not helping you anymore ...

Comment: I said about capistrano, capifony and composer and gave you log of deploying. Obviously this is issue in key forwarding, not in composer (I can do composer update normally on my localhost)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17297489/revisions ... not a single word about capistrano, jeah tag added but nothing in the question ... good luck with others helping

Comment: Sorry. I thought setting correct tags is means I deploying whith capistrano. Sorry for your time

Comment: the problem is related to your authentication towards github not ssh auth with the server ... doesn't matter if you deploy via capistrano ... if you want to use agent forwarding to access the github repository from the remote server during update make sure your agent is running and not being locked ! you don't need to privde the key in your deploy.rb if you use agent forwarding. try to ssh into your server, then execute `ssh git@github.com` and see what happens or just add your credentials to the composer.json as i suggested in my answer.

Comment: I have added my key on github and I can clone repos from github (my private or others) forwarding my key "$ ssh -A my_server; git clone ..". And while deploying via capistrano - 'composer update' cloned all other repos normally except this one..

Comment: what does happen if you manually clone the repo after ssh-ing into your server?

Comment: $ ssh git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi teplyakoff! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
                                                                                           Connection to github.com closed.

Comment: all fine. And only this repo "Mmoreramerino/GearmanBundle": "dev-development" asked me for credentials, and only if using composer update via capistrano)

Comment: `default_run_options[:pty] = true` in **deploy.rb** ?

Comment: `default_run_options[:pty] = true` - yes

Comment: do you have the ssh-agent running locally or does capistrano use the keyfile directly? comment out one of ssh_options[:keys] / ssh_options[:forward_agent] and try out

Comment: ssh-agent is running (my edit). after commenting out ssh_options it works as before. error at the same step

Answer (score 3):

### Using private GitHub repositories with composer

**HTTP Authentication**

either add your http auth credentials to the repository url in your composer.json (*not recommended*) for obvious reasons ...

```
"repositories": [
{
    "type":"vcs", 
    "url": "https://username:password@github.com/username/repository"
}
```

---

**SSH Key Authentication**

... or [register your publickey](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) at github to access your private repository using pubkey authentication. Make composer use this public/private keypair using:

```
"repositories": [
{
    "type":"vcs", 
    "url": "github.com:username/repository.git",
    "options": {
        "ssh2": {
            "username": "git"
            "pubkey_file": "/home/composer/.ssh/id_rsa.pub",
            "privkey_file": "/home/composer/.ssh/id_rsa"
         }
    }
}
```

... or ( **best solution** ), just add the public key to your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host github
  User git
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented out dependecy for

```
"Mmoreramerino/GearmanBundle": "dev-development",
```

and commited it to master branch.

After next deploying all fine but this dependency was not included.

I go to server with key forwarding:

```
$ ssh -A my_server
```

I went to `current/` directory, manually add this dependency in composer.json, did 'composer update'. Again it asked me my credentials. I entered it, all's ok.

After that I can deploy without troubles..

Because after I entered credetials was created `.composer/config.json` file:

```
$ cat .composer/config.json 
{
    "config": {
        "github-oauth": {
            "github.com": "blahblahsomehash"
        }
    }
}
```

Very strange..

May it is possible to tell composer to forcibly use git protocol, not https..